# MySQL how to create a correct index

Tags: mysql, indexing, b-tree, explain, sql-execution-plan

MySQL 5.5

I am trying to find the correct index for a query.

Table:

```
create table trans (
  trans_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  acct_id int(11) not null,
  status_id int(11) not null,
  trans_transaction_type varchar(5) not null,
  trans_amount float(9,3) default null,
  trans_datetime datetime not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  primary key (trans_id)
)
```

Query:

```
select trans_id
from trans 
where acct_id = _acctid
and transaction_type in ('_1','_2','_3','_4') 
and trans_datetime between _start and _end 
and status_id = 6
```

Cardinality:

```
select * 
from information_schema.statistics 
where table_name='trans'
```

Result:

```
trans_id                    424339375
acct_id                     12123818
trans_transaction_type      70722272
trans_datetime              84866726
status_id                         22
```

I am trying to find what is the correct index for the query?

```
alter table trans add index (acct_id, trans_transaction_type, trans_datetime, status_id);
alter table trans add index (acct_id, trans_datetime, trans_transaction_type, status_id);   
etc...
```

Which columns go first in the index?

The goal is query speed/performance.  Disk space usage is of no concern.

Answer (score 0):

The base of indexing a table is to make the queries light to improve performance, the first index to be added should always be the primary key of the table (trans_id in this case), and after that, the other id columns should be indexed too.

```
alter table trans add index (trans_id, acct_id, status_id);
```

The other fields are not needed as indexes, unless you query too often based on them.

Comment: Putting `trans_id` first makes the index unusable.  And it is redundant with `PRIMARY KEY(trans_id)`, which (in InnoDB) means that the data is a big BTree organized with trans_id first.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A**

Start with any `WHERE` clause that is `col = constant`.  Then move on to *one* more thing.

Suggest you add both of the following, because it is not easy to predict which will be better:

```
INDEX(acct_id, status_id, transaction_type)
INDEX(acct_id, status_id, trans_datetime)
```

**Plan B**

Do you really have only `trans_id` in the `SELECT` list?  If so, then it should not be bad to turn this into a "covering" index.  That's an index where the entire operation can be performed in the BTree where the index lives thereby avoid having to reach over into the data.

To build such, first build the optimal non-covering index, then add the rest of the fields mentioned *anywhere* in the query.  Either of these should work:

```
INDEX(acct_id, status_id, trans_datetime, transaction_type, trans_id)
INDEX(acct_id, status_id, transaction_type, trans_datetime, trans_id)
```

The first two fields can be in either order (both are '=').  The last two fields can be in either order (both are useless for finding the rows; they exist only for 'covering').

I recommend against having more than, say, 5 columns in an index.

[*More info in my Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

**Notes**

- Perform `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  You should see 'Using index' when it is a 'covering' index.
- I think the `EXPLAIN's` `Key_len` will (in all cases here) show the combined lengths of only `acct_id` and `status_id`.
- You are in a Stored Procedure?  If the version in the SP runs significantly slower than when you experiment, you may need to re-code to `CONCAT`, `PREPARE`, and `EXECUTE` the query.